# HDD low speed work

Tags: windows, hard-drive

I'm facing the problem that my hdd started to work slower. I thought it might be because the SATA/POWER wire were loose so I tightened them, it helped for some time, but now I face the same problem. So my question is, can it be again because of that? Or if the wires were loose it wouldn't even work at all? I deleted some apps to free the space, but almost the half of the 1tb is already free. What should I do? Run `chkdsk /f /r`?

Comment: What is the RPM spec?  If consumer 5400 rpm, it will be slow.

Comment: @John, I think it's 7200

Comment: Do a hardware Diagnostic test on the drive to see if there are errors. Once running a good 7200 rpm drive should appear fast.

Comment: Check the SMART report for this disk (and paste it here). You may use the free software CrytalDiskInfo for that.

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details: What is the exact make and model of the hard drive? What is the exact make and model of the motherboard you are using? What is the exact version of Windows you are using?

Comment: `can it be again because of that?` ... maybe it was never that

Comment: When HDD's start to slow down you may as well replace them with SSD's as they are much much faster. You'll probably find the disk performs better after a re-image or re-installing the OS, but it won't be long before it slows down again after a high file count starts to accumulate on them over time. Use clonezilla to clone your HDD to SSD and hotswap it - you'll be happy you did it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is almost certainly not related to the sata/power wire - it is conceivable but exceptionally unlikely.

It sounds like your hard drive is failing - slow speeds are a common sympton - and if thats the case you want to backup NOW and replace the disk.  You should look at its S.M.A.R.T result (Crystaldisk has a download that lets you pull this info for free).

Depending on your definition of slow, it could also be disk fragmentation.  A disk defragger will fix this.

Comment: Based on the lack of information in the posting I consider your following posting as pure speculation:

"It sounds like your hard drive is failing - slow speeds are a common sympton - "